# How to make full outer join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, join

I've searched and already spent a lot of time for this query...
What i want is i need to ouput the raw material name of the specific raw material while one of the columns are null. i've tried full outer join but i dont know why phpmyadmin doesnt accepts my query ive tried almost everything i can.

Tables:

purchaserequest_tbl

columns: purchaserequestID, orderID, rawmaterialID, rawmaterialquantity

rawmaterial_tbl:

columns: id, name, category, unit

here is the query

```
SELECT `purchaserequest_tbl`.`orderID` AS 'Order No', 
       `rawmaterial_tbl`.`rawMaterialName` AS 'Raw Material Name', 
       `purchaserequest_tbl`.`rawMaterialQty` AS 'Length (inches)'
FROM `purchaserequest_tbl`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `rawmaterial_tbl`
 ON `purchaserequest_tbl`.`rawMaterialID` = `rawmaterial_tbl`.`rawMaterialName`
WHERE `purchaserequest_tbl`.`purchaseRequestStatus` = 'Requested'
```

I hope someone will be able to help me.. im really having a hard time here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you, the query you posted worked for you, but didn't give the expected results. Full outer join didn't work for you because MYSQL doesn't support full outer joins, so you have to make 2 left outer joins in order to get this results, try this:

```
SELECT `purchaserequest_tbl`.`orderID` AS 'Order No', 
       `rawmaterial_tbl`.`rawMaterialName` AS 'Raw Material Name', 
       `purchaserequest_tbl`.`rawMaterialQty` AS 'Length (inches)'
FROM `purchaserequest_tbl`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `rawmaterial_tbl`
ON `purchaserequest_tbl`.`rawMaterialID` = `rawmaterial_tbl`.`rawMaterialName`
WHERE `purchaserequest_tbl`.`purchaseRequestStatus` = 'Requested'
UNION
SELECT `purchaserequest_tbl`.`orderID` AS 'Order No', 
       `rawmaterial_tbl`.`rawMaterialName` AS 'Raw Material Name', 
       `purchaserequest_tbl`.`rawMaterialQty` AS 'Length (inches)'
FROM `rawmaterial_tbl`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `purchaserequest_tbl`
ON `purchaserequest_tbl`.`rawMaterialID` = `rawmaterial_tbl`.`rawMaterialName`
WHERE `purchaserequest_tbl`.`purchaseRequestStatus` = 'Requested'
```

If you want only those that are null, add in both of the where clauses WHERE rightTable.Column is null

Comment: Thank you very much for the feed back my friend. Yeah i used it on a query builder to try 3 tables jst to make 2 left outer joins and it worked!

Comment: Your code is so great. Now i have another way to think of Queries! Thank you very much!!!